# show two colum from two tables in mysql with a UNION

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL query in which I had to get value from two different tables (Say a1, a2). For simple reason it works but as I have a UNION in the same query for an important reason (to get a value from table a2 to place in between a column value of a1) due to this my query result comes out to be odd. Here is my query and image which shows the duplicate entries of same TICKET_ID, I want to remove that, how?

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
 RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATE,
 TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKETID,
 PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT,
 PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
 CUSTOMERS.NAME AS NAME,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON AS REASON
FROM RECEIPTS
 INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
 INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
 RIGHT JOIN ADJUSTMENTS ON ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE
 (PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt'
 OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid')
UNION SELECT 
 ADJUSTMENTS.DATE AS DATE,
 ADJUSTMENTS.TICKET_NO AS TICKETID,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE AS PAYMENT,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT * -1 AS TOTAL,
 ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_NAME AS NAME,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON AS REASON
FROM ADJUSTMENTS
 ORDER BY NAME ASC, DATE DESC
```

and here is the output image of it

**Output**

[image]

Comment: wrap another query around the union and use that to filter the dupes?

Comment: would you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out, now the query becomes as below

```
SELECT
 RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATE,
 TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKETID,
 PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT,
 PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
 CUSTOMERS.NAME AS NAME,
 (SELECT ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON FROM ADJUSTMENTS WHERE ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE != 'adjustment' AND ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON != '') AS REASON
FROM RECEIPTS
 INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
 INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE
 (PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt'
 OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid')
UNION SELECT 
 ADJUSTMENTS.DATE AS DATE,
 ADJUSTMENTS.TICKET_NO AS TICKETID,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE AS PAYMENT,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT * -1 AS TOTAL,
 ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_NAME AS NAME,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON AS REASON
FROM ADJUSTMENTS
 ORDER BY NAME ASC, DATE DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  GROUP BY or just check the reason column not null

```
SELECT q.* FROM (

SELECT 
 RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATE,
 TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKETID,
 PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT,
 PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
 CUSTOMERS.NAME AS NAME,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON AS REASON
FROM RECEIPTS
 INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
 INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
 INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
 RIGHT JOIN ADJUSTMENTS ON ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE
 (PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt'
 OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid')
UNION SELECT 
 ADJUSTMENTS.DATE AS DATE,
 ADJUSTMENTS.TICKET_NO AS TICKETID,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_TYPE AS PAYMENT,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT * -1 AS TOTAL,
 ADJUSTMENTS.CUSTOMER_NAME AS NAME,
 ADJUSTMENTS.ADJUSTMENT_REASON AS REASON
FROM ADJUSTMENTS
 ORDER BY NAME ASC, DATE DESC ) q GROUP BY q.TICKETID
```

OR

```
 ORDER BY NAME ASC, DATE DESC ) q GROUP BY q.REASON !='' // q.REASON IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: well that worked but issue is the right side column of REASON is showing no data, why? it's empty!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work... It's hiding all the adjustment fields and showing only one, while I need to show all adjustment fields with or without reason column value :(